# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl' , when I try to make virtual environment in django

Tags: django, modulenotfounderror, fcntl

I have a windows 10 system. I'm trying to run Django project there. So installed virtual environment.
But when try to make virtual environment directory face some issue.
I have go through many solution but doesn't work.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

this code run ok

```
mkvirtualenv envname
```

here comes the error as  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'`

Install packages
pip list

```
altgraph                  0.17.3
asgiref                   3.6.0
auto-py-to-exe            2.36.0
autopep8                  1.7.0
Babel                     2.12.1
bottle                    0.12.25
bottle-websocket          0.2.9
cachetools                5.3.1
certifi                   2023.5.7
cffi                      1.15.1
charset-normalizer        3.1.0
colour                    0.1.5
cycler                    0.11.0
distlib                   0.3.6
Eel                       0.16.0
filelock                  3.9.0
fonttools                 4.38.0
future                    0.18.3
gevent                    22.10.2
gevent-websocket          0.10.1
google-api-core           2.11.0
google-api-python-client  2.87.0
google-auth               2.19.0
google-auth-httplib2      0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib      1.0.0
googleapis-common-protos  1.59.0
greenlet                  2.0.2
httplib2                  0.22.0
idna                      3.4
importlib-metadata        5.2.0
kiwisolver                1.4.4
macholib                  1.16.2
matplotlib                3.5.3
modulegraph               0.19.5
mysql-connector-python    8.0.33
numpy                     1.21.6
oauthlib                  3.2.2
packaging                 23.1
pandas                    1.3.5
pefile                    2023.2.7
Pillow                    9.5.0
pip                       23.2
platformdirs              2.6.2
playsound                 1.3.0
protobuf                  3.20.3
py2app                    0.28.6
pyasn1                    0.5.0
pyasn1-modules            0.3.0
pycodestyle               2.9.1
pycparser                 2.21
pygame                    2.1.2
pyinstaller               5.11.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2023.3
PyMySQL                   1.0.3
pyparsing                 3.0.9
python-dateutil           2.8.2
pytz                      2023.3
pywin32                   306
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
requests                  2.31.0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1
rsa                       4.9
setuptools                67.8.0
six                       1.16.0
sqlparse                  0.4.4
tkcalendar                1.6.1
tkmacosx                  1.0.5
toml                      0.10.2
typing_extensions         4.4.0
uritemplate               4.1.1
urllib3                   1.26.16
virtualenv                20.17.1
waitress                  2.1.2
wheel                     0.41.2
whichcraft                0.6.1
zipp                      3.11.0
zope.event                5.0
zope.interface            6.0
```

How can I solve it? Please help.